# How to cut off overlapping areas?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, user-controls, custom-controls

My problem is that I want to create my own custom Control. In this control there is only a rectangle. This rectangle can be rotated. When i e.g. rotate the rectangle for 45 degrees then the rectangle overlaps. But i want that the overlappinmg areas are cut off.

This is what it looks like now:

[image]

This is what i want it to look like:

[image]

Is there any way to do this with WPF?

Comment: @PhilippPloder : He must wait 15 minutes after asking his question before he can do so. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to, either programmatically or via XAML, set the control's [**`ClipToBounds` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.cliptobounds(v=vs.110).aspx) to `True`.

Via code in the constructor:

```vb
Public Sub New() 'VB.NET
    Me.ClipToBounds = True
End Sub
```

```cs
public yourControl() { //C#
    this.ClipToBounds = true;
}
```

Via XAML:

```xml
<yourControl ClipToBounds="True" />
```

Comment: Thanks, that´s exactly what i want!

Comment: @julien-100000 : No problem! Please remember to mark this as the accepted answer when the first 15 minutes of your question have lapsed. :)

Comment: sure :) @Visual Vincent

Comment: @julien-100000 : Also a little advice for the future: You don't have to write "@username" _**if**_ you're writing a comment to the person who wrote the post (although in this case I guess you had to since you need a certain minimum amount of characters to comment). -- Blah blah... In short: The current post's author will always be notified of a new comment. ;)

Comment: Okay, yes i needed the characters :D